# Why compiler doesn't choose rvalue-reference version of the `forward`?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I wrote a similar implementation of `std::forward` hoping to find out in which case the compiler will pick which version. The question is it seems never pick the **rvalue-reference** version.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::remove_reference;
using std::move;

namespace explicit_return {
template <typename type> type&& forward(typename remove_reference<type>::type&  value) { cout << "cp-"; return static_cast<type&&>(value); }
template <typename type> type&& forward(typename remove_reference<type>::type&& value) { cout << "mv-"; return static_cast<type&&>(value); }
}

void print(string const & value) { cout << "c:" << value << endl; }
void print(string &  value)      { cout << "l:" << value << endl; }
void print(string && value)      { cout << "r:" << value << endl; }

template <typename type> void explicit_print(type && value) {          print(explicit_return::forward<type>(value)); }
template <typename type> void indirect_print(type && value) { explicit_print(explicit_return::forward<type>(value)); }

int main()
{
    string a("perfect");
    indirect_print(a);
    indirect_print(move(a));
    indirect_print("forward");
}
```

Let's see the output

```
cp-cp-l:perfect
cp-cp-r:perfect
cp-cp-r:forward
```

Comment: `value` inside `explicit_print` is named object, so it is treated as *lvalue*. That is why always `forward(type&)` is selected. If you want to choose `forward(type&&)` you have to cast `value` to *rvalue reference*.

Comment: Yes, I see, just wondering why we even need `forward(type&&)`?

Answer (score 1):

Argument you pass to `forward<type>` is a variable, so a `l-value`.

you might have r-value overload selected with extra `std::move` or extra forward when it was a r-value for example:

```
template <typename type> void print_forward2(type&& value)
{
     print(explicit_return::forward<type>(explicit_return::forward<type>(value)));
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1843a26e5c579fa8)

In practice, I can imagine that storing arguments in `tuple` and reapplying them (once), something along:

```
print(std::forward<Ts>(std::get<Ts>(std::move(my_tuple)))...);
```

Comment: Thanks, make sense. Still a bit mysterious, do you mean `print(std::forward<Ts>(std::move(std::get<Ts>(my_tuple)))...);`?

Comment: @LanceLI: No, `std::get` has overload for rvalue `tuple`. But I think there are equivalent expression.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of you have declared `indirect_print` parameter as `type &&`, its value class is not an rvalue, but lvalue. Any named object is lvalue.

```
template <typename type>
void indirect_print(type && value) {
  explicit_print(explicit_return::forward<type>(value)); // `value` is lvalue here
}
```

That's why you're always call a `type&` version of your `forward`.

Remove `explicit_print` and `indirect_print` and rewrite `main` as:

```
int main()
{
    string a("perfect");

    print(explicit_return::forward<std::string>(a));
    print(explicit_return::forward<std::string>(move(a)));
    print(explicit_return::forward<std::string>("forward"));
}
```

and you will see the difference:

```
cp-r:perfect
mv-r:perfect
mv-r:forward
```